# Animating XY Line in TecPlot

Tags: animation, plot

I'm an environmental engineer using TecPlot to plot come charts with some input data, let me explain my problem.

I'm studying the evolution of a river bed with a Fortran code which I wrote. As a output the code gives a detailed stratigraphy going some centimeters under the soils surface. Basically the output file looks like this:

> 0.03500000000 -0.18093000000 -0.17093000000 -0.16093000000 -0.15093000000 ...
>   0.10500000000 -0.18100000000 -0.17100000000 -0.16100000000 -0.15100000000 ...
>   0.17500000000 -0.18107000000 -0.17107000000 -0.16107000000 -0.15107000000 ...
>   0.24500000000 ...

and so on.
The first column is the x variable (horizontal evolution) and has 200 data.

The other columns are the evolution on the vertical coordinate.
So basically for each line we have, starting from the second colon, an horizontal line drawn thanks to 400 values.

For example if I plot the entire first *column* with the entire first *row* what I get is just a line on the plot.

For each time step my Fortran code create an output file which gives a plot with all the substrate lines.

What I want to do, and I really don't know how to do it, is animating this plots in order to have, for each time step of the animation, the ENTIRE plot with ALL THE LINES.

What I've done in TecPlot so far is: 
1) import all the output files
2) put them in the XY Line plot of TecPlot using one zone for each output file I have (file 1 -> 1:ZONE001, file 2 -> 2:ZONE001, file 3 -> 3:ZONE001 and so on)
3) trying to turn them into contour plot (no results)
3.2) trying to animate them with XY Line plot animation (too bad, it animates every single line...)

I hope that I've been enough thorough to let you helping me.

I would appreciate each contribution and I thank You for each -even short, small- answer.

Best regards

Comment: I can send you an image of a plot, I couldn't insert it beacuse I don't have enough points, sorry.

Comment: You cannot do this without a script.  Probably best way would be to create all the linemaps and activate the sets of linemaps corresponding to each zone in a script.  If only Animate Linemaps could take a range of linemaps, instead of going through one at a time.

Comment: Thank You very much Mark. I finally decided to use Matlab, which I can use far better. In that way I managed to plot everything, save videos and also frames.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already loaded the file, and have multiple zones. you can animate the mappings by Animate -> Mappings.., As far as

> trying to animate them with XY Line plot animation (too bad, it animates every single line...)

is concerned, you need Map Skip value more than 1, to skip the mappings (lines). The animation can be saved as video or image sequences from the same dialogue box, by pressing the small video button besides the play rewind and forward buttons [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDi5x.png)